# Running SQL queries through web interface on Heroku

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm having trouble finding a web interface in Heroku to write SQL queries that can be created by app collaborators. I want to be able to query from a computer that doesn't have the heroku toolbelt installed as a collaborator.

Currently, I've been using the dataclips feature to do such a task, however it only allows the query to be modified by the app owner.

I'm not sure if I'm just misunderstanding how Heroku Dataclips works or just can't find a feature that allows collaborators to do such a task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Collaborators in your application can also modify dataclips. However data clips are intended to be a 'data clip' and not a webUI onto your database. Giving anyone the ability to update your application/data requires them to be a collaborator. Heroku provides no other security role than that.